# Непрописанные стили в HTML-письме

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email

При верстке HTML-письма откуда-то появляются лишние стили(особенность почтовиков). В mail ru все ок, в gmail и outlook есть лишние(не мною писанные) стили у тега `<p>`. Как исправить это и убрать отступы?

Письмо: https://romankushnarov.github.io/Email%20Order/index.html

Вот лишние стили(пытался "перекрыть" их,не вышло):

```
p {
display: block;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

Само письмо по ссылке: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMw3R0jHLL2s0BU8-k20hyNHGf4lAccq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Это стандартные стили браузера, они есть всегда и везде. И вопрос сводится к тому, почему gmail удаляет из письма ваши собственные стили

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ваши параметры стиля имели бОльший приоритет над другими, дописывайте в нужных строках `!important`

Пример:

```
p {
position:fixed !important;
padding: 4px 8px !important;
backgroundr:#777 !important;
}
```

Comment: Вот только это всё равно не поможет, если gmail все эти !important всё равно просто удалит из кода

Comment: Да, не помогает, есть какие-то другие способы решения данной проблемы?